# SQL Loop concatenation?

Tags: mysql, xampp

How to concatenate SQL column values and separate with a comma **(', ')**.

Note it should also terminate at null.

consider a table schema (assume all datatypes as varchar(100))

```
c1s | c2s | c3s | c4s |  c5s  | c6s | c7s
a   | b   | c   | d   | null  | f   | g
```

The desired output shall be:

```
a, b, c, d
```

Using MySQL Xampp

Comment: Why not retrieving everything from DB and then work on it. It sounds needlessly painful to do that in SQL which is not well suited for recursion.

Comment: Not a job for SQL. Compute the value in client code (PHP I guess).

Comment: @axiac I agree with your thought, but this is a smaller component of what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this you can use [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(",", t.foo, t.foo1, t.foo2) AS myfield FROM mytable t
```

Comment: That won't concat column values until one is `null` though.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have a while loop and you want to create a sql or string using that loop.

Below code snippet will help you. This is just a sudo code, you need to build according to your requirement:

```
cnt = 1;
noOfPartitions = 20;
SET @innerQuery = '';
SET @alterQuery = CONCAT('select query ..........( ') ;
WHILE cnt <= noOfPartitions DO
    SET @innerQuery = CONCAT('criteria .....');
    SET cnt = cnt + 1;
    IF cnt <= noOfPartitions THEN
        SET @innerQuery = CONCAT(@innerQuery, ', ');
    ELSE
        SET @innerQuery = CONCAT(@innerQuery, ');');
    END IF;
END WHILE;
SET @alterQuery = CONCAT(@alterQuery, @innerQuery);
SELECT @alterQuery;
```

This way you can create a dynamic sql or or create a string.